# comprobar que haya al menos un checkbox seleccionado LARAVEL

Tags: html, laravel, validación, checkbox

Tengo estos checkbox en mi formulario

```
<div class="form-check">             
  <label > 
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="presencial" name="presencial" value="1">
    Presencial
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
   <label> 
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="online" name="online" value="1">
       Atención remota
   </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="visita" name="visita" value="1"> 
      Visita domiciliaria
      </label>
</div>
```

Y los recibo en el controlador de esta manera

```
//Crear objeto de la modalidad
$modalidad_servicio = new ModalidadServicio();

//Asignar datos de los input al objeto
$modalidad_servicio->presencial = $request->input('presencial');
$modalidad_servicio->online = $request->input('online');
$modalidad_servicio->visita = $request->input('visita');
$modalidad_servicio->servicio_id = $servicio->id;

//Guardar la modalidad en la bd
$modalidad_servicio->save();
```

**La pregunta es:** Cómo puedo comprobar de que al menos uno de los 3 checkbox esté seleccionado

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría con un simple if

```html
if(!$request->input('presencial') and !$request->input('online') and !$request->input('visita')){

    session()->flash('error', 'Selecione al menos un checkbox');
    return redirect()->back()->withInputs();
}

//Crear objeto de la modalidad
$modalidad_servicio = new ModalidadServicio();

//Asignar datos de los input al objeto
$modalidad_servicio->presencial = $request->input('presencial');
$modalidad_servicio->online = $request->input('online');
$modalidad_servicio->visita = $request->input('visita');
$modalidad_servicio->servicio_id = $servicio->id;

//Guardar la modalidad en la bd
$modalidad_servicio->save();
```

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta, el dice **que al menos un checkbox** este seleccionado

Comment: Si no viene ninguno es obvio que no hay nada seleccionado

Answer (score 0):

La unica forma que encontre de hacerlo fue con js y acomodando un poco el html.

```
<div class="form-check">             
  <label > 
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="presencial" 
  name="presencial" value="1">
      Presencial
  </label>

  <label> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="online" name="online" 
  value="1">
  Atención remota
  </label>

  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="visita" name="visita" 
  value="1"> 
  Visita domiciliaria
  </label>

</div>


<script>
function validar_checkbox() {
   // Obtener hijos dentro de etiqueta <div>
   var cont = document.getElementsByClassName('form-check');
   var i = 0;
   var al_menos_uno = false;
   //Recorrido de checkbox's
   while (i < cont.length) {
      // Verifica si el elemento es un checkbox
      if (cont[i].tagName == 'INPUT' && cont[i].type == 'checkbox') {
         // Verifica si esta checked
         if (cont[i].checked) {
               al_menos_uno = true;
         }
      }
      i++
    }                 
    //Valida si al menos un checkbox es checked
    if (!al_menos_uno) {
        alert('Seleccione al menos uno');
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
          e.returnValue = false;
        }
    }
}
```